# "TypeError: Cannot read property '$router' of null" in vuetify

Tags: typescript, vue.js, prestashop, vuetify.js

I am trying to navigate to another page after clicking a button in vuetify but unable to do it. In the console it shows this error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property '$router' of null"
```

This is my code:

**ProductDetailsCard.vue**

```
<v-btn @click="this.$router.push({path: '/newpage'})">Next Page</v-btn>
```

This is my whole **ProductDetailsCard.vue** page `https://wetransfer.com/downloads/775193b11b70a8cd03372db08ee5a56a20200522072851/4d93e3`

**router > index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import NewPage from '../components/NewPage.vue';

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    base: process.eventNames.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
         {
            path: '/newpage',
            name: 'newpage',
            component: NewPage
        } 
    ]
})
```

If I change the code like this:

**ProductDetailsCard.vue**

```
<v-btn @click="NewPage">Next Page</v-btn>
.....
NewPage ( ) {
        this.$router.push({ path: '/newpage'});
}
```

Then it shows this error in the console:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Just write `$router.push`, `this` is for reference the vue component inside script.

```
<v-btn @click="$router.push({path: '/newpage'})">Next Page</v-btn>
```

Comment: It seems a bad router config. can you post the router added on main component(app.vue)?

Comment: This is my whole App.vue file- `https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3de3911ea44a0244f29d6ac0049362ae20200522072607/a2fb2d`